# Play games loadLeaderboardMetadata() returns outdated data

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm working on an app with Play Game Services, and I'm making a custom UI to display the list of leaderboards with only the score and the ranking of the player as dynamic data.

Then, when the user clicks on the score or ranking, he will be taken to the leaderboard default UI to display this particular leaderboard in details.

In other words: I'm making a custom UI for leadeboards list, but I use default UI for displaying a specific leaderboard.

I use loadLeaderboardMetadata() method to get the leaderboards data. The problem is it returns outdated data, even when I use loadLeaderboardMetadata(context, true) to force the reloading of data.

Moreover, if I click on an outdated score to display a specific leaderboard with the default UI, the data here is up to date ! ... and then, if I go back to my list of leaderboards and force the data reload, then the data for this specific leaderboard will be up to date (but not the data for other leaderboards).

Any idea and/or ways to work around that?

Thank you in advance,

Stéphane.

Comment: Do you have any recent fix for this problem? I am only using `loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore` but it returns old data if the user just submitted a better result.

Comment: Does it "fix itself" in released builds? Sometimes stuff likes this just doesn't work well in sandbox mode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that by using the loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore instead of the loadLeaderboardMetadata method, it seems to work.

Update: Except that this method is really slow if you have 30 leaderboards, and it throws error because you make to much call to the API's, so it is not a viable option. Except if you have very few leaderboards.

Comment: Except that this method is really slow for 30 leaderboards...

Submitted a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=74&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Platform%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: For me `loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore` returns old data for some unknown period of time. I'm not sure when it updates, if ever, during a session. If I do a round-trip to the native Google Play leaderboards and view the score there, then go back, the score is updated. Is this normal behaviour on Android? (Ok I just realized that this is probably the same thing happening as you describe in question - it only updates if the native UI for showing leaderboards is opened by the user at least once after a new score is submitted.)