# Google Play games: getRawScore does not get the local Score when offline

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am currently using Google Games Services trying to update the user score offline. This works fine as there is a cool feature for that:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/OnScoreSubmittedListener.html#onScoreSubmitted(int,
>   com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.SubmitScoreResult) if the
>   device is offline or was otherwise unable to post the score to the
>   server. The score was stored locally and will be posted to the server
>   the next time the device is online and is able to perform a sync (no
>   further action is required from the client).

So, imagine that the user has 100 points, The score gan grow to 200,300,etc. and will be updated when going online.

Unfortunately, when querying the score with [getRawScore](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore.html#getRawScore%28%29) The score returned is not the Offline one, but rather the last value from the server.

Is there any way to fix this? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's way worse than that: according to my tests, getRawScore() (or any other methods like getRank(), ...) return only the up-to-date data if you displayed the corresponding leaderboard with the default intent. If you never did, you won't even get a value.

See my post here: [Play games loadLeaderboardMetadata() returns outdated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216926/play-games-loadleaderboardmetadata-returns-outdated-data)

[Update] Apparently, you can use the loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore instead of the loadLeaderboardMetadata method. That one doesn't seem to return outdated data. Check it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore)

Comment: I will try to follow your post to see if we can get some good solution for this...