# How to retrieve user score from leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am using google play services leaderboard to upload the score of a user. Is there a way to retrieve the score of a user programmatically?

My use case is that I want to run multiplier game where users have level which goes up and down based on their wins/loses (sort of like stackoverflow reputation). I need to retrieve the old score to upload the new modified score.

How can  I do that? I didn't see this anywhere on the tutorials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can by doing something like that:

```
gameHelper.getGamesClient().loadLeaderboardMetadata(this, false);

/**
 * Called when the data is loaded
 */

@Override
public void onLeaderboardMetadataLoaded(int statusCode, LeaderboardBuffer leaderboards) {

    // If the fragment is currently added to an activity
    if (isAdded()) {

        // There's been an error on leaderboards loading
        if (statusCode != GamesClient.STATUS_OK) {
            if (leaderboards != null) leaderboards.close();
            // Error
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<LeaderboardVariant> variants;

        Iterator<Leaderboard> it = leaderboards.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            Leaderboard leaderboard = it.next();
            final String id = leaderboard.getLeaderboardId();
            variants = leaderboard.getVariants();

            // For each leaderboard
            for (LeaderboardVariant variant: variants) {

                if (variant.getCollection() == LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC &&
                    variant.getTimeSpan() == LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME) {

                    int rawScore = (int) variant.getRawPlayerScore();
                }
            }
        }               
    }
    if (leaderboards != null) leaderboards.close();
}
```

... but the reality is that you can't because the data is outdated, see here: [Play games loadLeaderboardMetadata() returns outdated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216926/play-games-loadleaderboardmetadata-returns-outdated-data)

It probably is a bug, but as there's no place to submit play-games bugs...

Anyway, why don't you keep a local copy of the scores you submitted? Wouldn't it be the easier way to do it?

[UPDATE]
It seems that you can achieve what you want by using the loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore instead of the loadLeaderboardMetadata method. That one doesn't seem to return outdated data. Check it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore)

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you for your help and suggestion. I guess I can. I just don't want people to cheat and change it. Plus be they uninstall the app, and install back again, data is gone

Comment: Or you can sync it to the cloud (with the same API) and encrypt local data. Or wait for a bug fix by Google...

Comment: Perfect! It seems thats exactly what I want. Accepted and +1 Thank Mr.Smart :) On another note,the leaderboard alwas accepts better score, right? I can't submit worse score (for purpose of adjusting someone level)?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you can't. You also can't reset user scores.

Comment: Are you saying that Android isn't able to detect a tampered app by the signatures we take pains to provide? I'm just vacillating between Java and C++ APIs but figured Java would do given all the keys and signing.

Comment: This method is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for the solution, according to the latest android releases,**the method described in the above answer is deprecated now**.

The Latest way to do it is as follows:

```
private LeaderboardsClient mLeaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, googleSignInAccount);    

private void updateLeaderboards(final String leaderboardId) {
        mLeaderboardsClient.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(
                leaderboardId,
                LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC
        ).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore> leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData) {
                if (leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData.get() == null)
                    mLeaderboardsClient.submitScore(leaderboardId, 1);
                else {
                    long currentscore = leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData.get().getRawScore();
                    mLeaderboardsClient.submitScore(leaderboardId, currentscore + 1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```